# XML-reader in PHP

Tags: php

I have a(n) XML-file :

```
<xml ..... >
- <tandlege_hansen>             // = dentist_hansen 
  <data var1 = "bla" var2="blabla" var3 ="blablabla" .... />
  <data var1 = "bla" var2="blabla" var3 ="blablabla" .... />
  <data var1 = "bla" var2="blabla" var3 ="blablabla" .... />
  .....
- <tandlege_hansen>
```

and in the PHP section I do the following:

```
<?php

$reader = new XMLReader();

if (!$reader->open("data.xml")) 
{
    die("Failed to open 'data.xml'");
}
....
?>

a lot of HTML-code 

<?php
    while ($reader->read()) 
    {
        if ($reader->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT && $reader->name == 'data')
        {
          $var1 = $reader->getAttribute('var1');
          $var2 = $reader->getAttribute('var2');
          $var3 = $reader->getAttribute('var3');
          .....
          ?>
          another - lots of HTML-code incluing "echo ($var1 .. $var3); .." 

<?php
        }
    }

$reader->close();

?>
```

This works well.

Now Dentist Hansen wants to change the XML-file like this:

```
<xml ..... >
- <tandlege_hansen>
  <week_01> 
  <data var1 = "bla" var2="blabla" var3 ="blablabla" .... />
  <data var1 = "bla" var2="blabla" var3 ="blablabla" .... />
  <data var1 = "bla" var2="blabla" var3 ="blablabla" .... />
  </week_01>    
 .....

// Numbers af lines (<data .. >) can be a random number between 1 and 64 independent of week_number (week_01).

  <week_52> 
  <data var1 = "bla" var2="blabla" var3 ="blablabla" .... />
  <data var1 = "bla" var2="blabla" var3 ="blablabla" .... />
  <data var1 = "bla" var2="blabla" var3 ="blablabla" .... />
  .....
  </week_52>
</tandlege_hansen>
```

The question is now:

```
while ($reader->read()) 
{
    if ($reader->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT && $reader->name == 'data')
```

Somewhere a place in here I need to:
read week_xx, 
extract week_numer (= xx), 
compare with actual week_number and reposition XML-reader-position to actual week (this_week = week_xx) (european standard) if found,
read XML-data (var1 -> var3 ),
show them and terminate

and how do I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

From the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/class.xmlreader.php):

> The XMLReader extension is an XML Pull parser. The reader acts as a cursor going forward on the document stream and stopping at each node on the way.

In other words, you cannot jump from one place in the document to another arbitrary position.

Furthermore, that class does *not* let you edit the Xml content in place, the most you could do is reading the Xml step by step and save it by writing it by hand back in the file.

A much *simpler* solution is to *not* use `XMLReader`, but instead use `SimpleXML` ([documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)), which loads the document as an editable tree. You could then use *xpath* queries to locate specific nodes of the document.

The downside is that since it loads the whole document at once, it may take a huge amount of memory if the document is big. Please consult the documentation for both classes for further information.

Comment: didierc : Thanks a lot. I did not know that. Thanks for the Link(s) to SimpleXML. I have tried now to almost 5 hours to make the idea work, but I can't . Don't know why. Have copied examples (bit by bit) and try to run it. Still error(s). It's better I go back to a MySql- solution - that seems to work. And starts working with the XML-solution later ..... Can open XML-fil and read it. Can't separate the data-items ..  I get nothing but errors from here.